# Use selectInput in shiny to plot different regression lines

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I am practicing some shiny app creating using the `baeskel` data in the alr4 package. My goal is to create a selectInput dropdown menu so the user can select which regression line to plot. I am uncertain how to arrange the code in the server part. So far, for one plotted line I have created this:

```
library(alr4)
data("baeskel")
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel("sidebarPanel", width=4),
                mainPanel(
                  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                              tabPanel("baeskal Data", tableOutput("table")),
                              tabPanel("Polynomial Regression", plotOutput("polyplot"))
                              )
                          )
                )
  )
  
server <- function(input, output){
  output$table <- renderTable({
    baeskel
  })
  
  x <- baeskel$Sulfur
  y <- baeskel$Tension
  output$polyplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(y~x, pch = 16,xlab="Sulfur",ylab="Tension",
         main = "Observed Surface Tension of\nLiquid Copper with Varying Sulfur Amount")
    linear_mod = lm(y~x, data = baeskel)
    linear_pred = predict(linear_mod)
    lines(baeskel$Sulfur, linear_pred,lwd=2,col="blue")
    })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

It works really well. My next goal is to add another regression line as follows:

```
quadratic_mod <- lm(Tension ~ poly(Sulfur, 2), data = baeskel)
quadratic_pred <- predict(quadratic_mod)
lines(baeskel$Sulfur, quadratic_pred, lwd = 2, col = "green")
```

However I would like to use the selectInput function as follows (not pictured in the sidebarlayout yet):

```
selectInput(inputId =  , "Choose Regression Line:", c("Linear", "Quadratic"))
```

I do not know how to choose the inputId so it can gather the information from each regression line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example that allows for different prediction models to be plotted in shiny.

In your `ui`, add the `selectInput` to choose the type of regression line.

In `server`, you can add an `if` statement to check this input, and determine which model to build from the data.

The appropriate predictions from the model and lines will be drawn accordingly.

```
library(alr4)
library(shiny)

data("baeskel")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(position="left",
                sidebarPanel(
                  "sidebarPanel", width=4,
                  selectInput(inputId = "reg_line", "Choose Regression Line:", c("Linear", "Quadratic"))),
                mainPanel(
                  tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                              tabPanel("baeskal Data", tableOutput("table")),
                              tabPanel("Polynomial Regression", plotOutput("polyplot"))
                  )
                )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  output$table <- renderTable({
    baeskel
  })
  
  output$polyplot <- renderPlot({
    plot(Tension ~ Sulfur, data = baeskel, pch = 16, xlab="Sulfur", ylab="Tension",
         main = "Observed Surface Tension of\nLiquid Copper with Varying Sulfur Amount")
    
    if(input$reg_line == "Linear") {
      baeskel_mod = lm(Tension ~ Sulfur, data = baeskel)
    } else {
      baeskel_mod = lm(Tension ~ poly(Sulfur, 2), data = baeskel)
    }
    
    baeskel_pred = predict(baeskel_mod)
    lines(baeskel$Sulfur, baeskel_pred, lwd=2, col="blue")
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I forgot about the if else! Awesome. This helped me get a base for then adding yet another regression line to choose from by nesting if else statements